# Algorithm to cut down number of comparisons to calculate chi-squared distance between histograms?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I'm working on a side project that will accept a source image and then produce a photo mosaic using a set of thumbnailed images it has available. I have an implementation that works OK (see below) but I'm running up against "big O" issues trying to increase the number of available images for replacement.

The process I'm currently using is the following:

- I pre-calculated 4 bucket RGB color histograms for all the available replacement images
- Scale up the source image to 1000x1000
- Create 20x20 "tiles" from the scaled source image and create 4 bucket RGB histograms for each tile
- For each tile, calculate the Chi-squared distance for each of the available replacement images
- For each tile, select the replacement image with the smallest Chi-squared distance

So concretely, the problem I'm running into as the number of available replacement images increases the number of comparisons grows exponentially. I'm currently testing with 25,000 available replacement images and it takes nearly 10 minutes to generate the final image across 4 cores on my laptop.

My question is, is there an approach I can use to avoid having the number of distance calculations grow exponentially?

One idea I had was calculating the distances between each of the goal "tiles", separating them into some N groups, finding an average histogram within the group and then finding the closest K available images to the average histogram. From there, I'd go back and calculate the closest matches for the tiles within each group but from a smaller source of the K closest images.

[image: Example mosaic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pragmatic answer is cheat.

Define several aggregate projections, like "average R", "average G", "average B".  Precategorize your images on these projections.  Do a preliminary score for each section to the thumbnails which is the sum of absolute differences between the image's projection and the thumbnails.

Now throw the thumbnails into a heap, and pull off the best 50.  Do your detailed calculation on that 50 and select the best one of those.

You might not pick the *perfect* answer.  But you'll pick a pretty good one.  And your necessary work per thumbnail is very small.  400 times you do 3 lookups, and a couple of comparisons.  Only a few make the cut to the real work.

Comment: Any thoughts on what a good "projection" to estimate against would be? I'd originally implemented this by averaging the (r, g, b) values of the thumbnails and minimizing the Euclidean distances between the tiles and thumbnails but the result was noticeably worse than Chi-squared distances of the histograms.

Comment: @AshishDatta The idea is to use the average (r, g, b) values to eliminate candidates that are unlikely to be a good match. That way, you aren't wasting time calculating the chi-square value of an all black tile against an all white tile. It may be worth trying to calculate some sort of variance across a tile. For example, if you can tell that the goal tile has low variance and is mostly red, you can likely find a good candidate from just those two criteria. With high variance, you probably want to try out a bunch of candidates.

Comment: Let's see.  Average R, G, B may work well.  You could also add in the averages for each quadrant as well.  In general the more projections you add, the slower things get.  Add enough and you recreate your current algorithm.  Also I threw out "best 50" as a guess.  The larger you make that, the more likely it is to get the best answer.

Comment: Are you essentially reinventing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Approximate_nearest_neighbor? See also http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/

Comment: @mcdowella No, this is not approximate nearest neighbor.  This is a simple k approximate nearest neighbors algorithm that provides a list of reasonable candidate nearest neighbors for the detailed check.

Comment: @btilly definitely works - http://imgur.com/a/k7XzR ! Which completed in 90 sec with the 25k possible. Any thoughts on how to maybe partition the candidate replacements so that I can only calculate the projection distances for images in the target tile's partition? Maybe cluster the average colors and compare the target tile to the centroid?

Comment: @AshishDatta You can put all candidate replacements into an R-Tree based on their projections, then find ones near the target tile's projection with a nearest neighbors search.  Note that to find everything in a sphere around the target point, you'll actually do work for everything in a somewhat larger enclosing cube, but you can still avoid *most* of your other images.